# msgraph permissions to read files from a specific SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I try the following combination (application permissions) to have access to all document libraries in a specific sharepoint site with msgraph client.

[image]

But i can get the document libraries from all sites.

```
var siteDocumentLibraries = await client.Sites[siteID].Drives.Request().GetAsync();
```

Any idea ; I want the Least privileged permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Files.Read.All` you should be able to access any files across all drives. I would recommend to remove this permission. Keep only `Sites.Selected` application permission.

What you need is to [add site permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-post-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and grant the role for your app.

I'm using Graph PowerShell SDK to add site permission.

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Application.Read.All, Sites.FullControl.All
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Sites

$servicePrincipalName = "your_service_principal_name"
$spoTenant = "tenant.sharepoint.com"
$spoSite  = "site_name"
$spoSiteId = "${spoTenant}:/sites/${spoSite}:"

$servicePrincipal = (Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$servicePrincipalName'")

$application = @{
    id = $servicePrincipal.AppId
    displayName = $servicePrincipal.DisplayName
}
# set read or write
$appRole = "read"
New-MgSitePermission -SiteId $spoSiteId -Roles $appRole -GrantedToIdentities @{ Application = $application }
```